# How to get siri to "Play my radio station"?

Tags: music, siri, apple-music

In general, when using Apple Music my most common option is to play "my radio station". I.e., this is a radio station made by Apple Music that incorporates my preferences and listening habits.

Traditionally, I would get siri to play this stations by saying: "Hey Siri. Play my radio station"

However, as of May 2021, this request only plays songs from my library. E.g., Siri responds with something like: "Now playing all songs in your library"

While I can go into my phone and click the radio station in Apple Music, I'd like to be able to issue a Siri command to play the station.

What is the current siri command for playing "my radio station"?

Comment: The command still works for me. An alternative is to request one of your smart mix playlists (“play my favorites mix”, “…new music mix”, “…chill mix”).

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? What happens if you say "play music I like"? What about "play my radio station from apple music"?

Comment: @JBallin Thanks for your suggestions. It is strange. The issues seemed to only last a couple of days. It is now back to normal. And yes "play music I like" seems to trigger the same behaviour.

Comment: Voting to close: Issue resolved itself, without indication of root cause or how to reproduce.

Comment: @jballin Sure. The answer seems to be that it was a short term issue. It seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: I have a similar issue. It started immediately after updating to iOS 14, and it eventually resolved itself, but again started happening immediately after the iOS 15 update. I'm telling Siri to "Play WNYC" (an actual radio station), and instead of playing WNYC, it always plays the song "My Sherona" by The Knack (which is on my phone). I can say "play radio station WNYC", which more or less seems to work, but to work around the issue, I wrote a shortcut ≠named "Play WNYC" that opens the WNYC stream.